# Will Stack Overflow sue me?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Am I Allowed To Make a StackOverflow Clone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/am-i-allowed-to-make-a-stackoverflow-clone)

Will I get sued if I create a website will almost similar functionalities (tags, vote up.down, related questions, badges) as Stack Overflow but for a different set of community (non-geek)?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes. We will sue you.

[image]

[YOU JUST GOT SERVED](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0899092/)

Comment: I can't determine if this is humorous or not :(

Comment: Me neither. Seriously, Jeff.

Comment: @Ian, Randell: I'm not sure if it's humorous, but it's supposed to be a joke.

Comment: Ok, as long as I'm not the only one :)

Comment: A Joke? You think my use of a Nintendo Power Glove is not *serious?*

Comment: I actually had a Power Glove - biggest waste of money ever.

Comment: yes, but I use mine to sue people

Comment: I'll let you sue me if you wear it to court

Comment: Don't worry, it won't be too invasive, I don't think @Jeff wants to get his power glove dirty.

Comment: Here's a pretty close clone of the Power Glove© on today's [Kids Woot!](http://kids.woot.com/Forums/ViewPost.aspx?PostID=4506004), I'm pretty sure Digital Blue should be sued too.

Comment: Always wondered what you would look like, Jeff.. And now I know. :)

Comment: @golez actually that's the character "Lucas", this actor. http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0899092/

Comment: @GolezTrol Wait, so that's not Jeff in that picture? :P

Answer (score 9):

Honestly, no. The functionality you've described has been done many times before, and no one owns the rights to any of it. If you make the site yourself you're good to go, provided you don't clone the site down to the CSS and HTML.

Comment: Agreed! As long as your site doesn't simply scrape the StackExchange network for your site's profit, a huge frustration mentioned many times before by Jeff & others.

Come up with a couple of extra features that make your site original. There are already several non-geek StackExchange sites available (scroll down to the bottom).

Answer (score 4):

Jeff et al. have the final word on this, but I seem to remember reading that the answer was no. There are already a few clones out there:

- [CNProg.com](http://www.cnprog.com/)
- [soclone](http://code.google.com/p/soclone/) - google code project
- [Stacked](http://ra-ajax.org/stacked-an-open-source-implementation-of-stackoverflow-com.blog)

Comment: Cool just checked out CNProg.com after awhile I figured out it was in another lang. pretty close clone.