# Could we see the intro video that was used in the DevDays?

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009, videos

For those who were [sitting at home crying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/whos-going-to-devdays/18349#18349). Could we see the [intro video](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20214/funny-devdays-intro-video-ideas) that was used at DevDays?

Comment: Yes! I was actually going to ask this – presumed it had already been done though.

Comment: Who's going to start the "DevDays reviews - Sitting at home crying"?

Comment: A bounty? I don't think Joel needs your rep ;)

Comment: The only way if I want someone to REALLY look at my question (as per the FAQ)

Comment: Don't trust the FAQ :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I asked Joel to post it, but he's hesitant for some reason...

Comment: Joel doesn't strike me as a person to shy away from controversial statements, surprised he wouldn't want an obviously over-the-top (hilarious) joke video seen.

Comment: you should run it by your crack legal team

Comment: Hmm, I'd love to see it. If it means getting sued by a bunch of expert transsexuals, so be it.

Comment: So do we need to ask Joel directly then?

Comment: The Pope might get upset?

Comment: @Sam Saffron: Wow, I read that as "run it by your legal crack team" and wondered what drugs have to do with it.

Comment: for context: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10630/will-stack-overflow-sue-me/10637#10637

Answer (score 7):

Fog Creek Customer Service to me

Hi Rip,

Joel passed along your email and asked me to get back to you.

We don't have it online unfortunately... although you're the 3rd to ask!

If there's any way I can help you further, please let me know.

Sincerely,
Michael

Comment: Hello Michael, you can help me by putting the video online. Thanks, SO users ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This video was **terrible** and should **never ever** be released to the public.

I find it personally **offensive and controversial** in numerous ways, and with its extremely **high production quality** it is poised to spread like a virus over the world wide web.

The effects of this could be devastating:

- Fog Creek Software, who is already flaunting how comfortable and cool they make their developers, stand to represent themselves as people who **both manage developers and have a sense of humor**. This puts tremendous pressure on both developers and managers to act human.
- By drawing parallels to a popular television show and character, and by focusing on several aspects of developer culture that are not mired in technical lexicon, this video may actually be found **humorous to non-developers**.
- This video makes it very clear, even if thinly veiled in tasteless humor, that people **without Asperger's** or other analogous social disorders are **disadvantaged as potential employees.** I have tried in vain efforts to make myself more marketable, to force myself to understand your world of lolcats and 4chan but I can not crack this glass ceiling.  **The prejudice needs to stop**, not be fueled by dissemination of this video.

I vote an emphatic **NO**.  You should be ashamed of yourselves.

Answer (score 4):

Found this very very average copy on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3slPNJdbF4) - you can't see much but at least you can hear it.

Comment: Ya I saw that, totally unwatchable.

Comment: Yeah agreed but at least you can listen to it. The real thing would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I attended the devdays Boston event and would love a copy of this video.

I think everyone should pressure Joel to post it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the intro demo is going to become Volume 7 - Management, of the [Make Better Software](http://training.fogcreek.com/included.html) training series.  That's why it hasn't been posted.

Comment: It's a fun intro video for the devdays people, don't see how its related to that.