# Is this Russian site a legitimate copy of the Stack Overflow package?

Tags: discussion, copyright

Russian IT Q&A site: [askdev.ru](http://www.askdev.ru/).

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37527/im-making-a-so-clone-am-i-copying-too-much-from-the-real-stackoverflow

Comment: Check out http://www.stackexchange.com, NOTE: I'm not saying that this Russian site is legit, just that there is a version you can buy.

Comment: Just from looking around (with no knowledge of Russian), it seems pretty clear that this is a (fairly close) copy and not a SE site.

Comment: I get the feeling that sneg X is the kind of guy who comments his changes in his code in spite of the fact that his source control does it for him anyway.

Comment: I know @Jeff hates email http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/11/is-email-efail.html, but really a direct question to a individual seems an abuse of the site.

Comment: @Urdnot: Oops, my bad. I forgot about the "trace" functionality.

Comment: @tvanfosson: I've addressed your concern. And the question is not about weather, you know. :)

Comment: @hat does "Q&O" mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that particular site is a clone. It's been around before Stack Exchange became available.

Answer (score 3):

Their site is a legitimate **clone** of Stack Overflow, but they are not affiliated with Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange.

I use their site, and I really like how it is implemented, although I use both askdev and Stack Overflow.

Comment: "legitimate" and "clone" would seem to contradict each other. How did they get to be a "legitimate clone"?

Comment: I don't know what legitimate mean to you, but I think legitimate mean they does not vilate any law. Is site clonning violate any law? NO.

legitimate in this case was just kind of sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

Their blog makes mention of Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow: http://www.askdev.ru/blog/. More specifically, their [Summary Post](http://www.askdev.ru/blog/08/2009/Sammary-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%86/) which seems to suggest that they hope to make the site more like Stack Overflow in the future, with regards to reputation-enabled editing.

Comment: Was that a very wild guess or do you actually speak russian?

Comment: Google translate ftw? http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.askdev.ru%2Fblog%2F08%2F2009%2FSammary-%25D0%25B7%25D0%25B0-%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B5%25D1%2581%25D1%258F%25D1%2586%2F&sl=auto&tl=en

Comment: @Pekka: I studied Russian for a while, but am no longer conversive. I can understand some, but not as well as I used to. Most of my day is spent speaking Portuguese, so it's a wonder I can hold English together :)

Comment: nice! How come you are speaking so much Portuguese? Has Atlanta been invaded by brazil? :)