# I'm cloning the StackExchange chat UI - yay or boo?

Tags: discussion, chat, community, clone

I'm working on a clone of the Stack Exchange chat. Many of the UI aspects of the SE chat are cloned entirely. The back-end, I'm guessing, is very different.

While I don't, of course, use a single line of code from Stack Exchange, and I know there are [no legal problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/am-i-allowed-to-make-a-stackoverflow-clone) in what I'm doing, I want to know what the community, and indeed Stack Exchange itself, think about such a project. Are there any reactions to similar projects from the past that I could look at?

- Note that **I'm not trying to build another community**. I couldn't ever hope of attracting the awesome people that visit SE, I am just working on the software, planning to release it under the **GPL** as soon as I've worked out the licensing of some of the dependencies.

  I might also (dual-) license the code to companies, if there's an opportunity. Can you also cite any community reactions to this kind of thing?
- *I'm not a disgruntled user!* I visit SE every day, I'm a community moderator on Ask Ubuntu, and I don't hope to attract the same people who visit any of the SE sites or the SE chat.

This is what it looks like (WIP):

[image]

I don't want this question to be an opinion poll. If you could cite reliable references, that'd be fantastic.

Comment: As someone who has tried this application, I have found that it works well and emulates enough of the chat.SE functionality that you could definitely use it for customer support, team collaboration, etc.

Comment: RE: not attracting users who "visit any of the SE sites or the SE chat." - it's too late for that, many of the Ask Ubuntu users have used it at one point or another, and will (probably) continue to.

Comment: You're not even the first to clone chat. A couple other users entered the Node Knockout competition recently with this: github.com/stackchat. I don't think it's officially blessed, but I know balpha was aware of it and much closer to "interested in helping" than "interested in filing a lawsuit."

Comment: [Prepare to be sued](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10630/will-stack-overflow-sue-me/10637#10637)

Comment: No anonymous read-only?  :(

Comment: As someone has wished for a long time for a SE chat clone, I thank you. SERIOUSLY looking forward to this.

Comment: Did you ever release this?

Comment: Echoing the previous question, did you ever release this?

Comment: @Andy Yes I did, [here it is](https://github.com/sfstpala/victorychat-ng).