# The Terms of Service prohibit editing other users' content

Tags: bug, status-completed, terms-of-service

The second paragraph of section 4 of [the Stack Exchange Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal), "Restrictions," reads:

> Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to ... (d) post any false, inaccurate or incomplete material or delete or revise any material that was not posted by You.

The part

> delete or revise any material that was not posted by You

technically prohibits editing of other users' posts. I guess the intent was to say "delete or edit other users' stuff in a way that makes this stuff worse," but the current wording fails to say that.

Comment: *Getting ready to sue SO and every user who ever edited a post of mine. **ever.*** And finally, there will be justice for all the "why was my post edited????????" users

Comment: @Pekka: Excellent! Sounds like `All v All` case is on the way.

Comment: And how about _[not post any] inaccurate or incomplete material_. There goes 90% of the questions...

Comment: Uh oh. I'm gonna be so banned!

Comment: @slh - see you in court! ;)

Comment: THinking about  a nice number to ask in damages. Should I take something flashy (like $88888888) or something geeky (like $2718281828)?

Comment: @Pekka $628. Obviously.

Comment: @Pekka - $3.1415926535897932x10^???

Comment: How about `$6.02e23`?

Comment: @JackManey - That's a _[mole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit))_ lot of simoleons!

Comment: Simple — just ban anyone with the editor badge :)

Comment: OMG, I have the Copy Editor badge! Does that mean I'm on some Most Wanted list?

Comment: Wait, people actually *read* that stuff?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

We're taking a look at this.  It may be a few days because it'll require going back and forth with the lawyer.

**Update**

We've amended the line

> (d) post any false, inaccurate or incomplete material or delete or revise any material that was not posted by You.

to

> (d) knowingly post any false, inaccurate or incomplete material.

Comment: So, since "incomplete" is still in there, does that mean that anyone who doesn't comply with requests to post more information (either on an answer or a question) is in violation of the ToS? It's better, but it still seems a bit more ambiguous than I would prefer.

Comment: Does the "knowingly" bit also mean that if your answer is shown to be wrong (eg. by another answer or a comment) that you are obligated to remove it?

Comment: @cdeszac It would be at the time you post it.  I don't believe there's anything in the ToS that obligates you to keep it correct forever

Comment: Good to know (for clarification purposes)

Comment: So, previously, you weren't allowed to post material that you didn't post?

Comment: [beware our crack legal team!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10637/1)

Comment: Seems like the Fastest Gun in the West Problem has been solved too! ;-)

Comment: I have knowingly posted incomplete material to be stay in line with an NDA. Oh noes.

Answer (score 47):

Whilst we're at it,

> post any false, inaccurate or incomplete material

This technically means everyone I've ever downvoted for answering a question wrongly is in breach of the ToS. And I'm probably in violation somewhere along the way as well.

We're also forbidden, technically, from using pseudonames:

> (c) create a false identity

Needless to say, my real identity is not, actually, Ninefingers, and is therefore false.

Suggested revisions to these sections:

1. Misrepresent any information as if authorative in such a way that its use may be detrimental to other subscribers,
2. Use an identity that wrongly implies expertise, knowledge or ownership of intellectual property belonging to another person, persons or organisation.

I am not a lawyer, I did just make those up, so please find a real lawyer to check those with. I'd say edit in corrections, but unfortunately if you do that, I'm gonna have to sue you.

Comment: Now that you've admitted that Ninefingers isn't your real name, I have no choice but to ban you.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I'm gonna have to request you ban yourself, too, Mr Lizard. Unless Lizard is actually your surname and "The" is actually your middle name.

Comment: `(c) create a false identity` _really_ means your screen name can't be "false"

Comment: But `FALSE` is okay?

Comment: Ahem, "identity" and "name" are not equivalent. "Ninefingers" *is* your identity, inasmuch as we can identify your posts as being posted by you, the user known as "Ninefingers". On the otherhand, *I* should be prevented from using a well-known identity, such as "Ninefingers". Obviously an identity with a screenname such as "John", "Jim", or "Mary" would not have such a restriction. "Alice" should be banned regardless.

Comment: I like "psuedonames". Does this mean I'm not allowed to call myself "Bob" but "hello" is fine :-).

Comment: @Ben `Bob`, `Mary` and `Alice` are known trouble makers ...

Comment: @cdeszaq Let username = !true ...

Comment: @Ben - Wouldn't a "pseudoname" be more like "B0b"? I mean, it's _almost_ a name in that it's _like_ a name.

Comment: @AviD Don't forget about that snooping biotch Eve...

Answer (score 12):

I think the clause about not posting "false, inaccurate or incomplete material" needs to be broken off from the editing portion and have "knowingly" tacked on at the front. And perhaps have the word "incomplete" removed entirely.

And "delete" doesn't matter, since users *can't actually* delete content (it's all soft-deleted, which means it's still there)

And the "revise" clause just needs "that was not posted by You" removed. And even then, since the edit history is available, it isn't *really* editing it as much as it is posting a new version (which has its own issues with plagiarism, but that's a *whole* different topic.)

<sub>Note: I am not a lawyer. The points expressed above are my own opinions and are not reflective of the opinions of my employer, state, country, planet, galaxy, universe, or any other body or organization of which I am a part.</sub>

<sub>Void where prohibited.</sub>

Comment: You forgot "may not be combined with other offers".

Comment: You'd end up with "Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to ... (d) knowingly post any false or inaccurate material or revise any material."

Comment: @ArdaXi - No, that's the point of "broken off from the editing portion"... To explicitly keep that from happening.

Comment: @cdeszaq Then maybe you should clarify?

Answer (score 8):

Thank you for making me read the Terms of Service for the first time...

I've just noticed the following in section 5:

> "Much of the Content of the Network is provided by and is the responsibility of the user or subscriber who posted the Content."

Which effectively means that everyone is responsible for any dodgy code they post ( not that anyone does of course ). There's lots of stuff indemnifying Stack Exchange from any responsibility for how the service is used by a "subscriber"; but nothing about the people who actually make the site work.

> "8. Indemnity
>
> Subscriber will indemnify and hold Stack Exchange, its directors,
>   officers and employees, harmless, including costs and attorneys' fees,
>   from any claim or demand made by any third party due to or arising out
>   of Subscriber’s access to the Network, use of the Services, the
>   violation of this Agreement by Subscriber, or the infringement by
>   Subscriber, or any third party using the Subscriber's account, of any
>   intellectual property or other right of any person or entity."

I don't know whether it's legally possible under US law but an additional sentence somewhere in the ToS along the lines of the following would be nice.

> Subscriber takes full and sole responsibility for use of any content
>   that has been posted by another subscriber. Except where such content
>   breaches another condition of these Terms of Service, Subscriber
>   indemnifies the provider of content in the same manner as Stack Exchange.

Or something like it...

Comment: While this is related (and interesting!), you should really post it as a separate Meta "question" if you want to see action taken on it.

Comment: @IuliusCæsar, you think; why? This question has had a lot of notice taken :-) and it's, as you say, related...

Comment: Answers aren't usually considered action items; they're just supposed to discuss what's raised in the question.