# Would this be infringement?

Tags: discussion, design, copyright, trademark

[image]

Would this be copyright or trademark infringement. I am inspired by SE's design, but wanted to check.

Comment: It is not using any graphics used by Stack Exchange sites, as far as I can see.

Comment: It's no different than any of the Stack Exchange ripoffs out there. At least you are doing something different instead of just sitting around with your drinking buddies going "Hey, I got an idea! Let's build a Q&A site! Dude it will be awesome!!"

Comment: I liked the layout that was done, and I wanted to create, code, and design my own similar to SE / SO. It's not going to be a Q&A network, but just a network of sites that are social networking sites. So no featues such as voting up / down will be used.

Comment: Thank you @jmort253. I have really good ideas. I hope to create the next Facebook or Twitter. Who knows. haha

Comment: It looks to me like you've just copied the fonts, the layout in the header basically. You'd really need an official "okay" if you want to be sure, and for that, you may be better served either emailing Stack Exchange or waiting for a community manager to post a comment or answer.

Comment: This is between you and your lawyer & Stack Exchange Inc. and their lawyer(s). I don't see how this is answerable on or applicable to Meta. It's a nice design, though!

Comment: That "okay" is very unlikely to ever come, though, on principle. You won't see a company say to a (potential) competitor, yeah, go ahead, use a design that resembles ours, we won't sue you.... For what it's worth: the design looks nice, but it clearly bears resemblance to SE, mainly because of the font. I guess that  is what made you ask this in the first place. Why not use a different one?

Comment: @Pekka: Well, I used Verdana, mainly because of it's plain and professional look, and it will work with most browsers. I'm not exactly sure which one SE uses. 

Edit: SE uses Helvetica. It's a similar looking, but different font.

Comment: Oh, the font in the logo is Verdana? I was sure it was whatever font SE uses and not Verdana... But that can be my tired eyes, I'm sitting in a bus. Still, SE comes to mind when looking at the design. You could reduce that resemblance without destroying the whole thing IMO. But then, it's probably not that important: they're unlikely to give a small project trouble over some esemblance; and if it really takes off, you'll refresh the design sooner or later anyway

Comment: @Pekka: Oh! I'm sorry. Yes, the logo is identical to the font used by SE's logo. So it's not your eyes. haha. I think that it is a great suggestion. I'm sure I can find another font for the logo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I am not a lawyer nor do I play one on TV*, so I can't really *approve* your design, *per se.* But the Trademark law is there to make sure that a reasonable person would not likely confuse someone else's sites with being a product of Stack Exchange. Our [Trademark Guidelance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) is to help you make sure your site looks sufficiently different to call it your own.

There are tons of Q&A sites out there that look virtually identical to ours in terms of layout, etc. We didn't invent the concepts of voting and wiki editing, but we feel that we've combined these elements in a way that makes them somewhat special. The biggest problems come when sites start reusing our our logos, CSS, code, or other non-user-contributed content without permission.

The key issue to consider is whether or not your site could be confused with ours. On the surface, I would suggest changing the name "Flux Exchange Network." It's pretty close to "Stack Exchange Network" as well as the speech-bubble-like logo. That would be a good start to clear up a lot of the any ambiguity and confusion.

Comment: FYI, the page you linked to says *> Do not copy the look and feel of our products*

Comment: I copied the CSS `body {color: #000000;}` the other day :P

Comment: @ajax333221 http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10637/115866