# I want a "Stack Overflow" for my community website

Tags: support, clone, legal

I administer a community website — currently on dotnetnuke, which can't change right now — and I'd really like to replace my forums with something like Stack Overflow, but it has to be on my site. My users need to be able to interact with each other, and also have integrated access to the site blogs, downloads, documentation, code (open source) and bug tracker. So I have two questions:

Since Stack Overflow no longer offers commercial hosting, would they stop me from legally creating/deploying a clone?

Do such clones exist already either as a DNN module, or asp.net (mvc?) website that I can add to my site?

Comment: FWIW, although SOIS no longer offers commercial hosting, it remains a commercial entity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of clones already out there.  See [Stack Overflow Clones?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) and [Am I Allowed To Make a StackOverflow Clone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/am-i-allowed-to-make-a-stackoverflow-clone) for details.

Answer (score 3):

You can suggest a StackExchange site over at area51.stackexchange.com.

If you have a legal question, you need a lawyer, not a programmer. Although you could also email "the team" (see link in footer) and just ask them.