# Where can I find a Stack Overflow style site

Tags: support, stack-exchange, clone

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [I want a “Stack Overflow” for my community website](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66143/i-want-a-stack-overflow-for-my-community-website)
>   [Where is the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq)
>   [Stack Overflow Clones?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

I am looking to implement a site which employs the same features as Stack Overflow but within the context of education.

Does anyone know what platform this site is developed on or any really good imitators out there? My favorite features are the related questions that pop up in addition to users being able to rate questions.

Bonus points if I can build a knowledge base and promote a particular question/answer in a forum post to the KB with a click.

Comment: how about proposing a new site at http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Already answered at meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Answer (score 4):

You can also suggest your idea for a site at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

There's a whole list of sites over at [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/37953#37953).  That list is actively updated by the community there.  For convenience, here is a snippet:

> **Most active that look like the best bets**
>
> - **[ASKBOT](http://askbot.org/en/questions/)** Django [code on github](http://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel). GPLv3. Based on CNPROG and some work for OSQA.
> - **[cahoots](http://cahoots.sourceforge.net/)**. PHP, CodeIgniter, Zend framework, MySQL. GPL, MIT license. [Example Site](http://cahoots.concentratedtech.com/) [Developer site](http://concentratedtech.com/). Seems to be under active development (v2.1 RC2 released 1 Feb 2010, as of Feb 2010).
>
>   Poor front-end website, but nice [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cahoots/index.php?title=Cahootsv2). Looks very full featured, but the example website is very cluttered. No doubt needs considerable customisation.
> - **[CNPROG](http://github.com/cnprog/CNPROG)**. Django. [Live site](http://www.cnprog.com/). GPLv3. Not a lot of recent activity; last code commit, Oct 2009 (as of Feb 2010). Primarily developed in Chinese, although there are English translations.
> - **[OSQA](http://github.com/OSQA/osqa/)**. Django. [Live site](http://www.osqa.net/). GPLv3. More actively developed fork of CNPROG.
> - **[shapado](http://gitorious.org/shapado)** Ruby, mongomapper and mongodb. [Live site](http://shapado.com/), also provide hosted sites for free. AGPLv3. Seems to be under active development as of June 2010.