# Would you consider it accurate to say SO clones contain SO's copyrighted site design?

Tags: discussion, design, copyright

It says here that look and feel is not copyrightable:  [Am I allowed to make a Stack Overflow clone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/am-i-allowed-to-make-a-stackoverflow-clone)

Will it still be correct to say that an SO clone "**contains designs from a copyrighted source**"?

**EDIT**

The site in question used to be a StackExchange 1.0 site that eventually migrated to one of the open-source SO clones.

Comment: Now there's a question for the lawyers ;p