# Building a new Q & A site like stack overflow. legal issues

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, legal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Am I Allowed To Make a StackOverflow Clone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/am-i-allowed-to-make-a-stackoverflow-clone)

Just a few questions in mind

Is it legal to build similar sites like stackoverflow.com which is functionally exactly the same. What if the site is on a very specific topic. I mean can we build an exact functional clone fo stackoverflow. Secondly can we borrow css from other stackexchange sites.

Comment: Write your own CSS.

Comment: _Exactly_ is the worst word to use here. _Borrow_ usually means you're going to give [the thing] back. _Other:_ you can propose SE sites on certain topics @ Area51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Gotta give the guy credit for asking, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we build an exact functional clone to Stack Overflow?

Yes.

> Secondly can we borrow css from other stackexchange sites.

No, the CSS is the intellectual property of Stack Exchange Inc. and is not avaliable for reuse. However, note that the look and feel may not be subject to the same protection in some jurisdictions.

However, consider already existing alternatives. You can propose new Stack Exchange sites at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) or you can use a open source alternative like OSQA.