# Is Locker Gnome ripping off Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, clone, copycat-sites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

I recently found [Locker Gnome](http://lockergnome.net/questions/) and I'm curious whether they're ripping off Stack Exchange, or are part of the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: LockerGnome is a site powered by [OSQA](http://osqa.net/).

Comment: Possible duplicates, at least related: [Am I Allowed To Make a StackOverflow Clone?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5558), [Stack Overflow clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267), [Stacked - an Open Source implementation of StackOverflow.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16780).

Comment: Perhaps we ought to direct people with Stack Exchange off-topic questions to Locker Gnome?  Seems like a win-win to me.

Comment: For anyone interested, one of our FAVORITE users from SO has apparently been active in OSQA for a month or so: http://meta.osqa.net/users/1763/genesis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's running on [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/), which is GPL'd, Django-based Q&A software, which appears to have very closely followed the design of the Stack Exchange sites.

It isn't affiliated with Stack Exchange (nor does it claim to be), and it doesn't mention Stack Exchange at all that I can see.

They even have a site at http://meta.osqa.net so if you want to ask them directly that would be the place.

Comment: Thanks for the OSQA link, and I thought as much concerning whether it was owned by StackExchange. I suppose the sincerest form of flattery is imitation, here.

Comment: … and it's great to see how that site is really failing on the "quality" part. Just take a look at the content there.

Comment: Which is why SO is the best place to be :D

Comment: "Very closely"? It's almost identical!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal - I was trying to write a neutral answer so people could follow the link and draw their own conclusions :).

Comment: @agf: Meh. Neutrality is overrated ;)

Comment: They have a pretty hilarious attitude, too.  They completely ripped off SE and then say they "don't care about Stack Exchange".

Comment: Also, wonderful example question from Locker Gnome for the quality evaluation: http://lockergnome.net/questions/165933/what-are-your-problems

Comment: @JNK Where do they say that? And that 'question'... Yeah...

Comment: @Jam - answer here: http://meta.osqa.net/questions/149/can-you-please-respond-to-this-question-on-meta-stack-exchange

Comment: @Jam exact quote is: `one thing StackOverflow and StackExchange aficionados will need to realize pretty quickly is that we don't care very much about StackOverflow and StackExchange. `

Comment: Well I suppose that's fair enough! This is highly a topic of personal opinion, but I don't mind SO being closed source; it's a great resource of information with an equally great community.

Answer (score 9):

OSQA — which powers LockerGnome — basically started off as an attempt to fork Stack Exchange when Joel and Jeff blindsided everybody with the 2.0 announcements last year. The idea was, as much as they'd deny it, to provide a refuge for anyone disenfranchised by Joel and Jeff's way of doing things. Their remit has since changed but this does explain the *virtually identical* layout and text.

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I have nothing to do with OSQA, and didn't even know that it existed until about ten minutes ago. I just read [this post](http://meta.osqa.net/questions/1050/dont-panic-stackexchange-is-not-the-goal).</sub>

Comment: Thanks for some of the behind the scenes stuff, Tomalak. There's too much competition and too many people saying "what you use is crap because I don't use it" in this world. OSS is about choice!

Comment: Actually it's about freedom, but okay.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh yes, I came across that site a few days ago.  It does appear to be a direct rip-off of Stack Exchange.  Including even the messages that come on top of the screen.

So the answer to your question is: Yes, someone is ripping off Stack Exchange.

The question really is: Is it breaking any laws?  What is open for use, what isn't?  Is there anything we can do about it?  Should we want to do anything about it?

Comment: the design is "inspired". Not sure if that's ripping off.

Comment: To your answer: thank you. To your last paragraph: no, but I don't think StackExchange is short of visitors. As I said in agf's answer, imitation is the sincerest form of flattery :-P

Comment: +1 for `Should we want to do anything about it?`. I'm a little bit sick of seeing people go all `you damn thiefs your stealing their copyright` on FLOSS clones of proprietary projects. If those clones succeed, it means they are better, it's called evolution. So far, Stack Exchange is doing very fine.

Comment: @Padded I completely agree - I don't mind OSQA being around; we've got SO with a lot of momentum behind it, with piles of great content (and some not-so-great stuff).