# Is this website a derivative of Stack Overflow, and is that allowed?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

I found [this](http://getthedata.org/) website on the web for 'Data related questions'. Is this some sort of related website, a clone, or otherwise? Is it legal?

Comment: Unleash the lawyers! ;)

Comment: There are several free software alternatives to the StackExchange engine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%26A_software#Comparison_of_Q.26A_software That's a good thing, original competition always is. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That site runs on [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/), a [Stack Overflow clone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones). It's not related to the StackExchange network.

I believe it is legal, that site has their own content and aside from copying the layout of StackExchange, they haven't actually lifted any actual code. See [Am I allowed to make a Stack Overflow clone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/am-i-allowed-to-make-a-stackoverflow-clone)

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I saw your linked Q but I thought it was worth asking. Looking round the site, I noticed they've imported some content: http://www.osqa.net/2010/03/ is that allowed, do you know?

Comment: All of the content on SE sites is under a cc-wiki license.

Comment: The SE [cc-wiki license requires attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) -- I just skimmed their homeschoolhelpdesk.com website and couldn't find a single attribution -- but the content there didn't look like it was the usual SE-level of quality either, so perhaps they "undid" their database import.