# Style thieves in the media?

Tags: discussion, copyright

I found this familiar looking voting widget on http://metro.co.uk (actually http://www.metro.co.uk/weird/876039-man-claims-140-year-old-photo-proves-nicolas-cage-is-a-vampire):

[image: voting widgets on metro.co.uk]

c.f.

[image: voting widget on SO]

To what extent might this violate Stack Exchange's licence on style/design?

<sub>It's worth noting that they didn't get the alignment quite right :P</sub>

Comment: The colors are slightly different as well (#999 vs #808185 on SO)... plus a selected vote on SO is a bigger arrow than the unselected, where-as on Metro they're the same.

Comment: How does the alignment not drive them crazy? I keep turning my head trying to make it right

Comment: The top-voted answer to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/am-i-allowed-to-make-a-stackoverflow-clone) seems to indicate that this is not a problem.

Comment: You might not know much about copyright and licenses, I don't know much either, but let me say this: Because something looks similar, doesn't mean anything. If they've copied code or questions from SE, let us know.

Comment: @Bobby: This discussion question absolutely _is_ useful. Just because "not at all" is a valid answer doesn't change that.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image\)

Comment: @Won't: I did crop it. Quite clearly. Thanks for your handy comment, though

Comment: It's two triangles and a number. It's not cold fusion.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman: Have you been following the billion-dollar patent wars going on at present over who first invented _a screen and three push-buttons_? That's hardly cold fusion either but, in many cases, this stuff _does matter_. Perhaps it shouldn't... but it often does.

Comment: Clicky... Can't see upvotes/downvotes, what a gyp! Their voting widget sucks; they didn't copy it correctly. In other news: *Nicholas Cage is a vampire?* WTF.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but you can anonymously vote

Comment: Since when is a discussion like this required to be _useful_ on Meta? It is useful to the user asking it. I kinda dislike the attitude of some users lately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not really infringing at all. Up-arrow, down-arrow, a number to indicate the vote count… pretty standard fare.

The Stack Exchange [**Trademark Guidance**](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) outlines what might be considered infringing. There's a lot of specific detail there, but the guiding principle is pretty simple:

**Is there any chance a reasonable person could confuse this product as belonging to, associated with, or endorsed by Stack Exchange Inc?**

If the answer is 'yes', then it is likely infringing.

Comment: To which I'd say "yes", frankly. But each to their own!

Comment: Seriously though, whether anyone cares about it or not, it's the exact same thing, obviously ripped off.