# Permission for Using SO website style for creating Similar Question and Answer site

Tags: discussion

Is there any permission required to built similar style of (Stackoverflow)? I reviewed both: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/ and https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/ but they not mentioned Website Style?

Comment: The web design is copyrighted. I doubt they'll let you use it.

Comment: If you want to build a Question and Answer website, then go right ahead. The *concept* is free for anyone to use.

Comment: The licenses you have quoted are about user generated content of the sites, not the site style.

Comment: @Oded: I knew that, that's why I asked this question

Comment: It's unlikely they are going to give you permission to copy their design. That said, it should be very easy to create a design that is different enough so your site looks distinctly different from SO. (You want that anyway, right?) The *basic idea* itself (like having up/down vote buttons, the question to the top, comments underneath) is not copyrightable.

Answer (score 5):

From the [legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal) page:

> The Network and its contents are intended solely for the use of the Network Subscribers and may only be used in accordance with the terms of this Agreement. All materials displayed or performed on the Network, including, but not limited to text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, and animations (collectively, “Content”) (other than Content posted by Subscriber (“Subscriber Content”)) are the property of Stack Exchange and/or third parties and are protected by United States and international copyright laws.

So, no, you can't use the styles in your design.

Comment: Ok I get it, then we should change the design to different concept and keeping the base same as SO.

Comment: @JasonOOO - Can't tell you what to do. But much has been discussed in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/am-i-allowed-to-make-a-stack-overflow-clone