# What are the legal issues concerning copying the look and feel of the name and logo of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, copyright

Suppose a commercial organisation decided to create a Q&A site that had the look and feel of Stack Overflow, calling itself Stocks&sharesOverflow.com, with a logo inspired by, but sufficiently different from stackexchange.com.

A [previous answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/am-i-allowed-to-make-a-stack-overflow-clone/16369#16369) stated that look and feel of a site isn't copyrightable, but what about modifying the name and logo of stackoverflow.com to maintain the same "feel"?

Comment: You're extremely unlikely to get a useful answer here - all the community can offer you is speculation. You should talk to Stack Exchange, Inc. directly, or to a Copyright lawyer, or give it a try and see what happens. That said, there is a site named http://mathoverflow.net/ that is not affiliated with SE any more... re the logo, just create a different one and save yourself the worry.

Comment: @Pekka Math Overflow's been an official SE2.0 site for a while now; it's linked in the footer of every Stack Exchange page, listed in the dropdown, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry - I somehow managed to overlook the big fat SE bar to the top. :) I stand corrected. (My more general point would be that it *may* be possible to get away with  "(xyz)overflow.com" even if SE don't like it, as it may not be possible for them to legally protect something that generic. But I don't know.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not going to get a definitive (or even an implied) answer to this here because any sort of legal issues tend to be rather case-by-case and your question is incredibly vague.

However, our trademark guidance can be found here: https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance.

Comment: The aforementioned MathOverflow site (the name is one word) is a counterexample to the statement "Currently, all Stack Exchange Network sites follow this convention: Server Fault (serverfault.com), Super User (superuser.com), etc." at the end of the document.

Comment: @127.0.9.6 Fun things like that happen when established sites join the network.