# Is the Awesomium help QA system a clone of StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, clone

Page:
http://answers.awesomium.com/index.html

Even the hint on question submission is practically the same.

Furthere investigation shows that has been made by these people:
http://answerhub.com/

Comment: Yes. One out of hundreds. AnswerHub is the first in there.

Comment: Nobody says nothing about this? Is it even legal?

Comment: It's legal as long as the design is not 100% copied. Stack Exchange does not have a patent over the upvote/downvote, badges, etc system.

Comment: This is really borderline stuff..

Comment: Well, there is a [5 years old discussion about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/am-i-allowed-to-make-a-stack-overflow-clone) and the answers there are still valid as far as I can tell.